# value is not updating of session array to json array via ajax

Tags: php, ajax, arrays, json

I have a session array **$_SESSION['Cartquantity']** . In php file on line no 200 I am storing this array in a variable **$QtyArray**

```
$QtyArray = $_SESSION['Cartquantity'] ;
```

then I am encoding the array in **json** to use it on js file

```
echo "var cartQty = " . json_encode($QtyArray) . ";" ; (on line 201)
```

Now via the **AJAX** I am updating the session array on line no 120 in the same way

```
$QtyArray = $_SESSION['Cartquantity'] ;                (on line 120)
echo "var cartQty = " . json_encode($QtyArray) . ";" ; (on line 121)
```

This is my javascript code to call file

```
$.ajax({
                    url:'index.php',
                    cache:false,
                    datatype:'json',
                    data:{ q: "add_card", item_id: id, item_qty: qty,stop:'1' },
                    success:function(data){
                        $("#cart_quanity").html(parseFloat($("#cart_quanity").html()))
                    }
                });
        return false ;
```

array is clearly updating because I can see this on console of firebug. But when I am getting this value on js file value is not changing. While if I reload the page where I update this value via ajax and then go to view quantity it is changing. Why is that happening ?

Please help!!!

Comment: How are you calling the javascript file?

Comment: I am setting the varaible in url and comparing in php file when it's true then executing the javascript.

Comment: Not exactly what I asked..  The javascript file.  How are you including it in the page?

Comment: Are you sure they are in the same scope ?

Comment: I am including js file in <head></head> as
<script src="controller/script.js" ></script> at line no 220

Comment: It seems odd to me that the AJAX-handler part is also returning a `var cartQty = ...` statement. I'd expect the php script to return just the data literal and then some javascript handler that assigns this data to the already "existing" `cartQty`.

Comment: @NiekvanderSteen Pardon Please I do not get your point

Comment: @VolkerK yes you are right that's why I am asking Please give me any answer if you have.What should I do?

Comment: Please outline what your script is doing, i.e. why, when and how you want to get the value of `$_SESSION['Cartquantity']` to the client/javascript.

Comment: @Shreya you said you are trying to re-define the JS var. If you don't do that in the same scope, it won't work. (i.e.: the first time it's global, and the second time from within a function or something)

Comment: Just show how you are handling the ajax request (client side)

Comment: @NiekvanderSteen I have changed $QtyArray = $_SESSION['Cartquantity'] ;                (on line 120)
echo "var cartQty = " . json_encode($QtyArray) . ";" ; (on line 121)

to 

$QtyArray = $_SESSION['Cartquantity'] ;                (on line 120)
echo "cartQty = " . json_encode($QtyArray) . ";" ; (on line 121)

but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Your server-side handler for the ajax request should just return the data literal itself.
On the client parse that data and then handle it there - not as a "complete" javascript snippet but just as an data object. JQuery supports you with the parsing part. Just let it auto-guess the type of the response or define it when calling $.ajax or $.post.

```
$.post(url, data, function(response) {
  // you cann assume response to be an object 
  // containing the data from the json-response of the server
}, "json");
```

self-contained example (doing nothing useful):

```
<?php
if ( isset($_POST['foo']) ) {
    // the client requests a new item
    $rv = array(
      'status'=>'ok',
      'value'=>rand(1,10)
    );
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($rv);
    die;    
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>...</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var total = 0;
                $(".foo").on("click", function() {
                    $.post("?", { foo: true }, function(data) {
                        if ( data.status && "ok"==data.status ) {
                            var newValue = data.value;
                            total += newValue;
                            $("#output").append("+ "+newValue+" = "+total+"<br />");
                        }
                    }, "json");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button class="foo">click</button>
        <div id="output">0<br /></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: so according to you what should I do

Comment: Just that: when handling the ajax request just return the data literal, in it's simplest form a) put the data you want to send to the client in an php array $rv b) echo json_encode($rv). On the client implement a response handler `$.post(... function(response) { ... }, 'json')` that does something with the data `from `response.

Comment: my reputation is 39 then why my account is blocked to ask question